# How to pass user input from one class to another in python?

Tags: python, class, variables, webapp2

I'm new to programming so there's probably a good chance I'm doing this wrong, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to write a program that has a form that takes user input in one class and then passes that to another class, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's a snippet of the relevant code (I put ***'s around the username variable, the one I'm trying to pass):

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  #this is in a form
   def post(self):
    ***username*** = self.request.get('username')

  #if username and other info entered correctly, then it redirects user to a new page and the WelcomeHandler class, so how do I get the username into the "Welcome, " message below?:


class WelcomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Welcome, " + ***username***)
```

EDIT: Here's my entire code, if it's helpful :

```
import webapp2
import re
import cgi

form="""

<form method = "post">   
Signup
<br>

<table>
    <tbody>            
      <tr><td><label>Username</label></td><td><input type="text" name = "username" 
 value="%(username)s"><div style="color: red">%(error)s</div> </td></tr>

<br>
     <tr><td> <label>Password</label></td><td><input type="password" name = "password" 
value="%(password)s"><div>TK TK TK</div></td></tr>

<br>
    <tr><td> <label> Verify password</label></td><td><input type="password" name = 
"verify" value="%(verify)s"><div> TK TK TK</div></td></tr>

<br>
    <tr><td> <label> Email(optional)</label></td><td><input type = "text" name = "email"
 value ="%(email)s"><div> TK TK TK</div></td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<input type = "submit">
</form>
"""


def escape_html(s):
    return cgi.escape(s, quote = True)

def valid_username(username):
    USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
    return USER_RE.match(username)

def valid_password(password):
    USER_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
    return USER_RE.match(password)

def verify_password(password, verify):
    if verify == password:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def valid_email(email):
    USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
    return USER_RE.match(email)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, error="", username="", password="", verify="", email=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {'error': error, "username": 
escape_html(username), "password": escape_html(password), "verify": escape_html(verify),
 "email": escape_html(email)})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()


    def post(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')
        verify = self.request.get('verify')
        email = self.request.get('email')

        username_check = valid_username(username)
        password_check = valid_password(password)
        verify_check = verify_password(password, verify)
        email_check = valid_email(email)

        if not (username_check and password_check and verify_check):
            self.write_form("That's not valid, you jive turkey", username, password, 
verify, email)
        else:
            self.redirect("/welcome")

class WelcomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Welcome, " + username)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainHandler),
        ('/welcome', WelcomeHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to do this. This isn't just normal class-based programming: each of those classes represents a request made from the browser to your server. What would it mean to pass that data between classes?

What you actually want to do is to tell the browser to redirect to your GET handler.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a GET handler, but how would I redirect it to a GET handler without using a different class?

Comment: You *do* have a GET handler. That's what your `WelcomeHandler` is.

Comment: Oh. D'oh! In that case, my code does redirect to my WelcomeHandler. But the WelcomeHandler doesn't seem to have access to the username variable. I assumed it's because it's in a different class, but maybe that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [setting cookies](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies) and [reading cookies](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#guide-request-cookies) in the webapp2 doc.

Answer (score 1):

Just what Daniel said - you need to understand the HTTP request/response cycle and how your RequestHandler **instances** are tied to it.

The usual solution here is to use "sessions" - a mecanism that persists data from one request to another for a given user usually identified by an opaque key stored as a cookie in the user's browser. FWIW, any decent web framework should provide support for sessions, so you may want to read your framework's doc here.